# cygwin installation

Tags: download, cygwin, installation

i am trying to install cygwin on my laptop running Windows 7 64 bit.
according to the official site, it is recommended to download and install individual packages as it takes much time. so i installed one by one but the problem is that at the end of every installation, an error appears. "Download incomplete. Try again?"
is this doing it because i haven't installed all packages or because the download for the package i chose was incomplete/unsuccessful?
if the latter, how can i fix this problem?

i am downloading from the mirror sites. http://mirrors.xmission.com and http://mirrors.kernel.org

Comment: Well, I got this problem too, and it seems that the problem is that some files are blocked by the firewall. I solve this problem by using a Shadowsocks proxy :D

Answer (score 3):

Try to run the setup.exe as Administrator. It worked for me. Right-click on the exe -> Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin setup finally worked for me, - “make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found"

Cygwin 32bit for windows 8 64bit system crashed a lot of time, finally i deleted the earlier downloaded files and then again i choose mirrors.kernal.org (Also others may work), this time at 99% it crashed but i had chosen "TRY AGAIN - NO" it skipped some library and finish its process. But it worked work for me, when i tried make command in the shell i got "“make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found" . Which means success.

Refer - www.ee.ryerson.ca/~courses/ee8218/cygwin.doc‎

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 7 machine using the standard setup.exe found [here](http://cygwin.com/install.html) has worked. Individual packages can be installed and removed by running the setup.exe at any time

Comment: I run Cygwin on my windows 7 laptop without issue. Yes, the first download takes forever, but it's always worked. I use the hoobly mirror.

Comment: i downloaded the setup.exe from that site too.. do you know what may be causing this problem? in the directory, i can see zipped files downloaded to the localpackage directory i assigned. no more than that.

Comment: the hoobly mirror returns immediate download incomplete error

Answer (score -1):

Now finally I have my cygwin Setup which is setup-x86_64.exe worked on my machine:

So during the Installation or Cygwin Setup,

the point where one reach to **Select Your Internet Connection**

Select the radio button for Use Internet Explorer Proxy Settings

Now the next windows will be **Select Packages**

And Select Desired Packages:

Example: python
ssh
vim
emacs

Install and enjoy..